Page break right before tikzpicture misplaces annotation
When using \tikzmarknode from the TikZ library tikzmark to annotate an equation, it can happen that a page break occurs just right before the tikzpicture. This then places the annotation at the bottom of the next page. How can I prevent a page break before the tikzpicture environment (\nopagebreak does not work)? Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{51em}
\begin{equation}
  y = \tikzmarknode{m}{m} x + n
\end{equation}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[<-] (m) -- ++(0,3.5ex) -- +(10ex,0);}
\end{document}



You can move the tikz earlier:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{51em}
\begin{equation}
  y = \tikzmarknode{m}{m} x + n
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[<-] (m) -- ++(0,3.5ex) -- +(10ex,0);}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Thank you very much! It works perfectly! I don't know why I haven't tried moving the tikzpicture inside the equation ...
